# How to convert '2021-08-24T11:00:19Z' to datetime and find days between it and the current time in django

Tags: python, django

I get the following publishedAt string `'2021-08-24T11:00:19Z'` from youtube's api for the video object. But I don;t understand how to convert it into a datetime object and find the hours between it and current.

I tried the below code but it didn't work

**view.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

today = timezone.now()
publishedAt = datetime.fromtimestamp('2021-08-24T11:00:19Z')
daysOld = (today - publishedAt).days
```

But I am getting the below error at this line `publish_date = datetime.fromtimestamp('2021-08-24T11:00:19Z')`

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I don't understand how to convert the string to datetime object and get the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you provide here is datetime formatted by the [ISO 8601 standard [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can parse this with the [**`parser.isoparse(…)`** method [Python-doc]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) from the [**`dateutil`** package](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import isoparse
>>> isoparse('2021-08-24T11:00:19Z')
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 11, 0, 19, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

You thus can install the package with:

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

and then run this with:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.parse import isoparse

today = timezone.now()
publish_date = isoparse('2021-08-24T11:00:19Z')
diff = today - publish_date
```